# d3 Force: Making sense of data binding

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I can recreate the following 1000 times and have enough of an understanding to do so. But I'm trying to get my head around a few specific bits that I just 'do', rather than understand:

```
var w = 900,
    h = 500;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h)
    .attr("style", "border: 1px solid grey;")
    .on("mousemove", fn)

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .size([w, h])
    .on("tick", tick)
    .gravity(0)
    .charge(0)
    .start()

function fn() {

    var m = d3.mouse(this); 
    var point = {x: m[0], y: m[1]};
    d3.select("#output").text(force.nodes().length)     

    var node = svg
        .append("circle")
            .data([point])
            .attr("cx", function(d) {return d.x})
            .attr("cy", function(d) {return d.y})
            .attr("r", 0.1)
            .transition().ease(Math.sqrt)
            .attr("r", 5)
            .transition().delay(1000)
            .each("end", function() {
                force.nodes().shift()
            })
            .remove()   

    force.nodes().push(point)   
    force.start()
}

function tick() {
    svg.selectAll("circle")
        .attr("cx", function(d) {return d.x})
        .attr("cy", function(d) {return d.y})
}
```

In particular it's the data binding part I'm not sure about.

In function fn() (on mousemove of svg space) we define a new point and we need to do two things with it; push it into force.nodes() so that the x and y coordinates of the point can be manipulated by forces configured in the force layout, and we need to use the coordinates of the point to create and manipulate the visualisation.

So we create the point first off. We then build a circle to represent this point. We push the point into force.nodes() and after a short delay, we remove both the visualisation and the point from the force.nodes() array.

The bit I don't understand is how the visualisation and the point in the array stay "connected"?

Conjecture: The data point is an object which the force layout is constantly updating the x and y properties of. There is a "link" to this object bound to the circle element. The object is therefore easily accessed and used by the circle object, but not without us controlling that process. The circle is defined as having a cx and cy at point of its creation, but we need to keep accessing the underlying data to update its cx and cy?

If that's the case, how is the object "shared" by both force.nodes() and the circle element?

Or am I miles off the mark?

Also I have read a lot of documentation on this but I feel this is something more intrinsic to javascript rather than d3 necessarily, so it's not elaborated on in any literature I've so far read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link between the data structures that the force layout updates and the visualization (i.e. the DOM elements) is the `tick` event handler function. The `tick` event is generated by the force layout to signify that the force simulation has progressed another step (i.e. tick) and its internal state has changed. This signals that the visualization needs to be updated.

There are two parts to making this link happen. First, the data operated on by the force layout (i.e. the links and nodes) needs to be bound to DOM elements. This is done using the usual `.selectAll().data().enter().append()` pattern, usually in the initialisation code, sometimes in the `tick` event handler function. This establishes the link between data and DOM elements.

The second part to this is the code that updates the DOM elements when the force layout changes their positions. This is what happens in the `tick` event handler function. If you're not adding or removing elements, there's usually no need to rebind data and often you won't see the `.selectAll().data()` pattern, but only the code that actually updates the positions based on the data already bound to the elements (in your case this works even though you're changing the elements because the data binding happens in the function that updates the data for the force layout as well).

As an experiment, take an arbitrary force layout example and delete the `tick` event handler function -- you'll see that nothing happens at all even though the force layout is running.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. "This establishes the link between data and DOM elements." - this is the part I need elaborating. Was I correct in my conjecture above when I said that the data array is a collection of objects, changing the x and y coordinates in force.nodes() on each tick also changes the x and y coordinates of the data point attached to the circle in the DOM becomes it's the same thing? The same object?

Comment: Yes, by binding data to a DOM element using `.data()` or `.datum()`, you're making them the same -- in particular both will reference the same actual object.